# Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) and an Asynchronous Object

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I'm using ARC in an iOS app i'm building.

I've created some objects, in which they connect to a web server asynchronously to download data.

I noticed that when I `alloc` the object, it sends the request fine, but when it is time to receive ARC has already `dealloc`'d the object, so that app crashes. Putting the variable in my header file solves this problem. But my concern is that If I've got a lot of these types of objects, wont memory usage go up? (Particularly when I no longer need the object once they're finished)

Is there a better way to handle this in ARC, perhaps something similar to the old `[NSObject release];`

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `@property(retain)` for your instance variable in your header file.

Set this property to `nil` once you are done with it (once you have received the response -- or error -- for your request for example) so the memory will be released by ARC.